# Erro ao simular distinc em consulta com Linq e lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Possuo 2 tabelas em um banco SqlServer. Uma chamada tbEstado e outra tbCidade. Estou tentando retornar todos estados da tabela tbEstado que possuem pelo menos uma cidade(tbCidade) e com as propriedades tbCidade.bnlAtivarCidade e tbCidade.blnExibirNoPortal = true. O resultado deve ser ordenado em ordem alfabética pelo nome do estado.

Estou tentando assim:

```
IQueryable<tbEstado> ListaDeEstados = ctx.tbEstado
            .Join(ctx.tbCidade, estado => estado.idEstado, cidade => cidade.idEstado, (estado, cidade) => new { estado, cidade })
            .Where(e => e.cidade.bnlAtivarCidade == true && e.cidade.blnExibirnoPortal == true)
            .Select(e => e.estado)
            .GroupBy(e => e.idEstado)
            .Select(group => group.First()).OrderBy(e => e.txtNomeEstado);
```

Mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Additional information: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver? Lembro que passei por algo parecido e fiz uma gambiarra. Tipo `ListaDeEstados` recebe a lista normal (sem ordenação) e depois você ordena.. sacou??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscar todos os estados que estão associados a cidade pesquise no repositório de cidades.

Ex.

```
ctxCidade.Where(...).Select(x => x.Estado).Distinct().ToList();
```

Envie suas Entidades Cidade e Estado. Parece ter algo errado ai.

Comment: Mas isso não pode ser feito porque no OrderBy não terei acesso as propriedades da tabela como por exemplo txtNomeEstado. Afinal aí terei um conjunto de registros.

Comment: Envie suas entidades Estado e Cidade para que eu possa dar uma olhada

Comment: São super simples. tbEstado tem Id(int) e Nome(nvarchar). Já cidade tem Id(int), Nome(nvarchar), AtivarCidade(bool) e blnExibirnoPortal (bool) e idEstado(int). Apenas.

Comment: cidade tem que ter referência para estado. Está estranho. E se quiser estado poderá ter uma lista de cidades.

Comment: Cara o erro não está nas entidades. A consulta funciona perfeitamente no sql. o problema está ao passar para expressao lambda. Especificamente o trecho [.GroupBy(e => e.idEstado)
            .Select(group => group.First())] Que só existe para simular o distinc. Se retiro esse trecho tbm funciona, mas vem vários estados repetidos.

Comment: No SQL Server posso fazer assim que dá certo: SELECT DISTINCT tbEstado.idEstado, txtNomeEstado FROM tbEstado inner join tbCidade 
                      ON tbCidade.idEstado = tbEstado.idEstado 
       WHERE tbCidade.bnlAtivarCidade=1 ORDER BY txtNomeEstado ASC

Comment: Mas para buscar todos os estados que possuem cidade você poderá usar o linq para filtrar cidades e dar select nos estados usando distinct. Ex.: ctxCidade.where(...).Select(x => x.Estado).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Nem sempre você deverá olhar o modelo de objetos como se fosse modelo relacional. Tente a estratégia que coloquei acima. O linq acima retornará uma lista de cidades.

Comment: Entendo. Mas por uma questão semântica realmente gostaria de buscar começando pelo estado... De qualquer maneira, testei e funcionou direto com um .distinct(). Mas aí fica a dúvida. Afinal quando posso usar distinct() e quando preciso usar a gambiarra do .GroupBy(e => e.id) .Select(group => group.First()) ???

Comment: GroupBy é usado apenas em conjunto com funções de agregação (Count, Max, Min). para fazer apenas o distinct ordenando por nome use o orderby mesmo. Groupby pelo Id é desnecessário. Não irá agrupar por nada já que id é único.

Comment: O teste que você fez foi usando a solução proposta ou a sua?

Comment: Foi usando as 2. Ambas funcionam com distinct() , dispensando a gambiarra do GroupBy. Vou marcar como respondida. Afinal a dúvida agora é outra e por tanto para outro topico. "Quando posso usar distinct e quando preciso forçar distinct com a gambiarra do GroupBy"? Talvez eu crie outro tópico. Mas este acabou. Obrigadão!